# Best way to smoothly move a character from one point to another

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game where if the user taps the screen their character moves from one point (say left side of the screen) to another point (right side of the screen) smoothly.

I know you can do this a few ways: Coroutines, Lerp or even an animation. I wouldn’t mind code examples as well..

What are some different ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "best"...

Comment: the "Best" way is really subjective... but it would be helpful if you gave some examples of exactly what you need.  For example does this system need to worry about collision detection?  Are you using any form of path finding?

Answer (score 3):

Well `best` is mostly opinion based and not a good way to ask actually... anyway

What the other answer didn't mention:

Of course the smoothness doesn't come from `Vector3.Lerp` nor `Coroutines` but actually from the [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html).

This `Time.deltaTime` value is the real time passed since the last frame. This allows to do all kind of smooth and especially always taking the same amount of real time movements and actions independent of the frame rate.

In terms of the specific usecase of movements I personally would prefer the usage of [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) over `Vector3.Lerp` because the later gets slower and slower as it gets closer to the target. (At least if you use the transform.position as first value as often done in examples)

Here is the example provided by the Unity scripting API

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;
    void Update() {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

Instead of `target.position` of course you can also just define a `Vector3` as target position.

If you need collision detection than both shouldn't be used because you might just move the object to far in one step so the collision isn't triggered.

In this case you might find a hint in [this post](http://answers.unity.com/answers/368845/view.html)